# Website MVC object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a member page once the user has logged in. My Login function works fine but i am unable to receive member info to the view.When using breakpoint on the view i receive the model object as null.

Comment: It seems like your setup isn't quite right.  Your `Models.customer` model is  automatically bound to the HTTP request.  If you're using that model on login (which you said is working) then it is dependent on form input fields called `email` and `password`.  Your member page most likely does not have these fields, so the model binder can't build your model. I'll try to add an answer to illustrate this.

Comment: When you do `return RedirectToAction("MemberInfo");` it will not pass the pass an appropriate query string on so that the model binder on `MemberInfo(Models.customer em)` is able to create a model, so it will be null. The prior call `MemberInfo(c);` you are pretty much just calling a method and discarding the value.

Comment: if you `return MemberInfo(c);` then it will not redirect to another page, ie it won't change the URL, it will just execute the action method and return the relevent view. A `return RedirectToAction("SomeAction")` will return a 301 redirect to the browser and redirect it to "SomeAction" so the browser URL will change.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to redirect to MemberInfo view after successful login?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Gist I created that serves as an example of what you might traditionally do after a successful authentication in MVC.

- https://gist.github.com/xDaevax/76aec2867494c0b1d0d8

It leverages the default model binder when necessary, and doesn't when it's not.

After your user is logged in, if you're storing their information in a session variable, you don't need to pass an argument to your member action, you can simply load it from the session.

Traditionally, MVC actions in controllers should be simple, not have much business logic (they should have a repository or service layer), and *typically* shouldn't call other action methods as functions (they're not functions, they're actions).

Let me point out some relevant portions of the code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AuthDemo.Models;
using AuthDemo.ViewModels;

namespace AuthDemo.Controllers {
    public class LoginController : Controller {

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel();

            return View("Index", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logon(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
            // The default model binder has already performed basic validation against the request, so we check against that
            ActionResult result = null;

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                // Continue with login
                // Perform some back-end user validation
                bool isValidLogin = false;
                // var isValidUser = this.MembershipRepository.ValidateUser(loginRequest);
                // TODO: perform operations based on the boolean.  For now, we pretend it's true
                isValidLogin = true;
                if (isValidLogin) {
                    Session["user"] = new UserModel() {
                        FirstName = "Clara",
                        LastName = "Oswald",
                        Email = "oswin@thetardis.com",
                        Id = 5
                    };
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Session["user"].Email, false);
                    result = RedirectToRoute("MemberHome"); // Landing page for authenticated users.
                } else {
                    // The user wasn't found in the repository
                    LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
                    viewModel.LogOnRequest = loginRequest;
                    viewModel.LogOnResponse.Successful = false;
                    viewModel.Messages.Add("Could not find the user specified.");
                    viewModel.LogOnRequest.Attempts += 1;
                    result = View("Index", viewModel);
                }
            } else {
                // Login failed
                LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel(); // Build a new instance of the view model so we can show validation errors
                viewModel.LogOnRequest = loginRequest;
                viewModel.LogOnResponse.Successful = false;
                viewModel.LogOnRequest.Attempts += 1;
                viewModel.Messages.Add("Invalid login");
                result = View("Index", viewModel);

            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the login controller above, I have two actions, one for the initial Get request for login, and one for POST.

The post action has 3 possible courses of action:

1. The user input was valid and we found the user (happy path)

   In this case, we load the user information from our database, assign a session value, and set the authentication token.  Once complete, we issue a Redirect response and return that from the controller.
2. The user input is invalid (bad input, failed regex, etc...)

   In this case, we check the ModelState for problems and return a Strongly Typed ViewModel to the view that contains their original request (to persist the form field values) as well as any custom messages telling the user what is expected.
3. The user input is valid, but the information isn't found.

   In this case, it is much the same as with invalid input, but we need to indicate this differently to the user so we apply a different message.

The `RedirectToRoute` function provided by the base controller will take the user to the appropriate place after setting the property values.

Once in the `MemberController`, there is no need to have a request argument as the user did not perform a post but was redirected from a successful login.  In this case, we need only load the data saved from the login and do whatever else needs to be done, as seen below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AuthDemo.Models;

namespace AuthDemo.Controllers {
    public class MemberController : Controller {
        //
        // GET: /Member/

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            UserModel user = (UserModel)this.Session["user"];

            return View("Index", user);
        }

    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense and clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

MemberInfo method return ActionResult object, that you do not use.

Try this code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.customer cs )
{

        if(isValid(cs.email, cs.password))
        {
            Session["user"] = cs.email;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(cs.email, false);

            customer c = customerEntity.customers.Single(e => e.email == cs.email);
            return MemberInfo(c);
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Authentication Failed");
        return View(cs);
}
```

Comment: Action results should not return null... ever...  How will you communicate that the login failed?

Comment: Returning the Action Result of MemberInfo inside the Index body did not resolve it. It remains on the login page rather than redirecting the view of MemberInfo Method. @dima_horror

Comment: 2. Check namespace of model. (I have had cases of the same class names)

Comment: 3. On View page Model is null, but NullReferenceException not throw?